# Techniques for rendering multiple simple objects

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering

I want to render simple objects of an amount in the order of 10^2 to 10^3. As for now these objects are just cubes (or 12 triangles) with colors and normals. 
The cubes' heights, widths and positions will vary between each other.
These properties will be created based on pseudo-random calculations.

The properties will not change before the player moves to a certain location. So nothing change per frames, but everything changes at the same time when a location is reached.

So what I'm doing now is:

- Initialize by filling 3 buffers: Vertex positions, Normals and Colours
- The buffers hold all the information for all cubes present in the scene
- The whole buffers are sent to a simple shader using one glDrawArray() call
- When a certain location is reached, all positions, normals and colors are recalculated for every object and the whole buffer is updated using glBufferSubData()

With the amount of object I have now, this update of the buffers takes a bit longer than desired and is very noticeable. I also plan to add bit more properties and details to the cubes and this will increase this time even more.

Given this simple description of what I am currently doing, are there any rendering techniques I could use to improve the time of updating the buffer?

(I am using OpenGL with C++)

**EDIT**

- Is there maybe a way to update a complete buffer more efficiently?
- Update the buffer step by step..?
- Could I somehow make the buffers hold less information (only each cubes center position) then let the shaders somehow "do the rest"?

Comment: How about parallelizing ?

Comment: Where in the process would this be used, and what exactly would parallelize?

Comment: You said it is the buffer update which takes time, so parallelize the loop which does that. Also, I am shooting in the dark here because of the absence of any code sample in the question.

Comment: Yes I skiped the code as I'm just starting by looking for some general methods. I will probably end up with a new more specific question when I'm in the right direction. 
But ok, can give me a pointer in how to get started with parallelizing the loop, or a short idea what exactly that would mean. I'm pretty new in this.

Comment: Divide your buffer into say 'X' chunks, instantiate X number of threads. If you have C++11, use `std::thread` or `std::async`. The function executed by `std::thread` will work on an input range provided as the argument. So, you will end up creating X threads which will update the X ranges (non-overlapping) of the buffer (which would be shared amongst the threads.)

Comment: I've always thought getting into thread division was something very complicated, but let me check that and see how it goes.Thank you @Arunmu :)

Comment: No problem. Between, if you have used  `openmp` then it's much easier to parallelize code using it, though I have no experience with it.

Comment: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing